# How to use/not-use cache on a per-request basis?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, ehcache

I have a Hibernate + Ehcache + Spring MVC webapp that is setup in a pretty standard way:

Controller -> Service class -> DAO class -> DB

The app is a REST API and it responds to HTTP GET requests with XML.  Everything is working as expected.  The DB is only hit when needed--otherwise results come from Ehcache.

What I would like is to use/not-use the cache on a per-request basis.  I'd like the default behavior, of course, to be to use the cache but when a "nocache=1" parameter is passed in, the cache should NOT used and the DB should be read instead.

I started going about adding a "useCache" parameter to my service class methods and then to the DAO classes but that didn't feel right.  Is there a nicer/better way to do this?  Perhaps with a servlet filter of some sort?

Comment: +1, how do you configure your cache? Hibernate? `@Cacheable`?

Comment: I annotated my POJO classes with @Cache(usage=...).  Also I specify the cache names in my ehcache.xml file.   
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea, but am not sure if it is proper.

Write 2 methods, one with `query.setCacheable(true);` and another normal one. Now, when you can use the methods as per your need ie, when you need caching and when you don't.

Here is [article](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-two-the-query-cache/) which speaks about the Query Cache.

Comment: That is (almost) exactly the route I started going down but didn't like the way the caching stuff polluted my code.  I felt the business methods in my service classes shouldn't have to "know" about caching so I stopped.  Still wondering if there is an AOP or filter way of achieving what I want...